# I am not getting Jquery datepicker value on submit button from UIGRid

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have set jquery Datepicker in UI-GRid cell as below:

```
{ name: 'RDD', displayName: 'RDD', cellTemplate:'<input type="text" class="datepicker"  id="{{row.entity.PartID}}"  ng-model="row.entity.RDD"  ng-value="row.entity.RDD" ng-click="grid.appScope.datepicker(row)"  width="10px;" />',width:"*" }, 

and datepicker function as:-

 $scope.datepicker = function(em)
   {
         alert('Do you want to change');
        var RowID = '#' + em.entity.PartID;
        //$(RowID).datepicker('show');
       // alert(test);
      $(RowID).datepicker(
      {
         minDate: 0,
         dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
         {   
            $(RowID).val(""); 
            $scope.$(RowID).val(dateText) ;
            //$('#36').val(dateText);         
         }
      });
   };
```

When I click on textbox datepicker is open and selected date is displayed in textbox .

But when I click on submit button the grid is return me old value(i.e database value) not selected by datepicker value

Can any one face this issue & help me in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I have changed 
{ name: 'RDD', displayName: 'RDD', cellTemplate:'<input type="text" class="datepicker"   id="{{row.entity.PartID}}"  ng-model="row.entity.RDD"  ng-value="row.entity.RDD" ng-click="grid.appScope.datepicker(row)"  width="10px;" />',width:"*" }, 

//To
{ name: 'RDD', displayName: 'RDD', cellTemplate:'<input type="text" class="datepicker" ng-change=""  id="{{row.entity.PartID}}"  ng-model="row.entity.RDD"  ng-value="row.entity.RDD" ng-click="grid.appScope.datepicker(row)"  width="10px;" />',width:"*" }, 

//and added change event in datepicker function:-
$scope.datepicker = function(em)
   {
         alert('Do you want to change');
        var RowID = '#' + em.entity.PartID;

      $(RowID).datepicker(
      {
         minDate: 0,
         dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
         {   
            $(RowID).val(""); 
            $(RowID).val(dateText).change() ;


         }
      });


   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change ng-model variable and get assigned name at that time when you want it to save in DB.

```
{ name: 'RDD', displayName: 'RDD', cellTemplate:'<input type="text" class="datepicker"  id="{{row.entity.PartID}}"  ng-model="selectedDate"  ng-value="row.entity.RDD" ng-click="grid.appScope.datepicker(row)"  width="10px;" />',width:"*" },
```

***selectedDate*** variable will get always updated date.

Comment: I have added ng-model="selectedDate" but still i am not getting updated value from:- $scope.gridOptions.data .  How to update selectedDate or fetch updated value from selectedDate?

Comment: Have you initialize $scope.selectedDate = ''; in your controller when it's loading or page loading? If not then initialize it like this, let me know.

Comment: Yes i have initialize the $scope.selectedDate = ''; in controller before data is assigned to UIGrid

Comment: ok then now it must should have the problem with in your template, make sure it is working correctly.

Comment: Template is working fine without giving any error. When i insert manual date in same textbox, updated value fetched but when date selected from jquery datepicker not fetched.